# UICollectionView Issue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Xcode 10 beta 5, iOS 12.0 16A5339e
I use the UICollectionView inside my app with the following code:

```
extension MainWindowViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemMenuArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if let itemCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "main_menu_cell", for: indexPath) as? MainWindowCollectionViewCell {

        let item = itemMenuArray[indexPath.row]
        itemCell.refresh(item)

        return itemCell
    }

    return UICollectionViewCell()
}
```

And the problem is that method `.refresh` executes for separate cells when I scroll my CollectionView. So the cell that is out of the screen updates every time I scroll into its direction and causes wrong cell colors sometimes. Are there any ideas how to fix that?

`.refresh` code (I use that in my custom cell class):

```
public func refresh(_ menu: Menu) {

    Title.text = menu.name

    if let image = menu.img {
        Image.image = UIImage(named: image)
    }

    print(SubscriptionTitle.text!)

    self.setupCellAppearance(firstColor: UIColor(hexString: (menu.firstColor)!), secondColor: UIColor(hexString: (menu.secondColor)!))

}
```

`setupCellAppearance` code:

```
func setupCellAppearance(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor) {        
    // Setting up the gradient for each cell
    clipsToBounds = true
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    // Setting up the corner radius and shadows for each cell
    self.layer.shadowColor = firstColor.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 5.0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath        
}
```

Comment: Show the `setupCellAppearance` method

Comment: I edited question

Comment: Each time in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` you call `refresh()` that call `self.layer.insertSublayer()`. I really hope that you remove theses layers in `prepareForReuse()` because cells (`UITableViewCell`/`UICollectionViewCell`) are reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happening is `cellForItemAt` reuse the cell so every time cell is reuse which might already having gradient layer with it and you are trying add a new gradient so that creating a different color. So you need to remove the layer if its already there, to remove layer set `name` property of `CAGradientLayer` with some unique name and then before inserting in layer check layer with that name already exist, if it exist remove it.

```
func setupCellAppearance(firstColor: UIColor, secondColor: UIColor) {

    //Check gradient is already exist
    for layer in self.layer.sublayers ?? [] {
        if layer.name == "BGGradient" {
            layer.removeFromSuperlayer()
            break
        }
    }

    // Setting up the gradient for each cell
    clipsToBounds = true
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()

    //set name property of gradient layer
    gradientLayer.name = "BGGradient"
    gradientLayer.colors = [firstColor.cgColor, secondColor.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
    gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 0)
    gradientLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0
    self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)

    // Setting up the corner radius and shadows for each cell
    self.layer.shadowColor = firstColor.cgColor
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 5.0)
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 10
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    self.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    self.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.layer.cornerRadius).cgPath

}
```

Comment: @MrBlazOn Welcome mate :)